# Number of $p$-groups with order $p^k$ and $|Z|=p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, groups-enumeration

What is known about the number of groups of order $p^k$ with $|Z|=p$ , which I denote $N(p^k)$ ?

For $k=1$ , it is clear, that we have $N(p^k)=1$ : We have one group of order $p$ and since it is abelian, we also have $|Z|=p$.

For $k=2$ , we have $N(p^k)=0$ : We have two groups of order $p^2$, both are abelian, so $|Z|=p$ is impossible.

For $k=3$, we have $N(p^k)=2$ : There are $3$ abelian and $2$ non-abelian groups. Since $|Z|=p^2$ is impossible, the claim follows.

For $k=4$ , I conjecture that for $p>2$ we have $N(p^k)=4$. For $p=2$, we have $N(p^k)=3$. GAP approves this for $p\le 1000$.

For $k=5$ , I also checked the primes upto $1000$ and noticed that $N(p^k)$ is one of the numbers $10,14,15,17,19,21$. So, I conjecture this is the case for every $p$.

> Is there a proof for the two conjectures ?
>
> Can $N(p^k)$ be estimated for larger $k$ ?
>
> Does $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{N(p^k)}{gnu(p^k)}=0$$ hold for every $p$ , where $gnu(p^k)$ denotes the number of groups of order $p^k$ ?

Comment: In general, as soon as the prime exceeds the exponent, the possible groups are a lot more manageable (being regular). So if one fixes the exponent and lets the prime grow, it seems reasonable that the number of such groups should stabilize.

Answer (score 2):

Groups of order $p^4$ and $p^5$ are classified, so it should be a matter of chasing references to check your conjecture. The following is a good starting point:

Besche, Hans Ulrich; Eick, Bettina; O'Brien, E. A. A millennium project: constructing small groups. Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 12 (2002) 623–644.

EDIT:
As for your second conjecture, I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: I haven't come across that estimate for $N(p^k)$. Do you know where that comes from?

Comment: I have to admit I didn't check very carefully. I've seen it quoted in various places that almost $p$-groups have class $2$. I think one can show that the number of groups of order $p^n$, class $2$ and center as small as possible is at most say $p^{O(n^{5/2})}$. I realise now that this, together with the earlier fact, is not enough. I'll try and have a closer look if anything can be recovered.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, my earlier reasoning seems silly. If most $p$-groups have class $2$, it seems more reasonable to expect that a typical $p$-group with small center would have class $3$. One would then many choices for the group modulo the center and, using a modified version of Higman's construction, one might even be able to show that the number of such groups is also at least $p^{\frac{2}{27}n^3+O(n^2)}$. One would just have to add some conditions to make sure the center doesn't grow.

Comment: I don't think that it is easy to construct a large number of groups with class $3$ and centre of order $p$. Starting with groups of class $2$ in which $Z(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$ are large elementary abelian groups, a class $3$ descendant with centre $Z$ would arise from a "faithful" bilinear map $G/Z(G) \otimes Z(G) \to Z$, and with $|Z|=p$ this would not be possible. So I wopuld not be surprised if a bound for $N(p^k)$ had been proved.